# PHP not rounding floats properly?

Tags: php

I am trying to round the double `0.0045`. When I call...

```
echo round($theFloat, 3);
```

I get 0.004, instead of 0.005 which is the expected response.

Here is the code:

```
$increase = 1.1;
$previousPrice = round(0.11 / $increase, 2);
$nextPrice = round(0.11 * $increase, 2);
$afterCut = round(0.11 * 0.95, 6);
$willSend = $afterCut - $previousPrice;
echo round($willSend, 3);
```

Comment: `var_dump($willSend);` and see what you got.

Comment: Can you echo $willSend to verify what is getting passed to round()?

Comment: Check all your inputs, code looks fine.

Comment: I know it looks fine, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it and why it rounds it to 0.004!

Comment: echo round(0.0045,3); this is giving output as 5.

Comment: Yes, but round($willSend, 3) gives me 0.004.

Comment: is $willSend having value 0.0045 ?

Comment: Yes, $willSend has 0.0045

Comment: @gladoscc - Post the exact value of `$willSend` by doing a `printf()` of it: `printf("%2.10f\n", $willSend);`. It is likely that displaying that value will show you what's wrong (i.e. the value is actually `0.00449`, but displayed with 4 decimal places, it is `0.0045`.

Comment: `var_dump(number_format((float)$willSend, 50, '.', '')); //string(52) "0.00449999999999999011901508083610679022967815399170"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what you have *looks* like 0.0045, the value is *actually* approximately 0.00449999999999999966, since [IEEE 754 floating point values cannot specify exactly that number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). And *that* value, when rounded to 3 places, is 0.004.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$increase = 1.1;
$previousPrice = 0.11 / $increase;
$nextPrice = 0.11 * $increase;
$afterCut = round(0.11 * 0.95, 6);
$willSend = $afterCut - $previousPrice;
echo round($willSend, 3);
```

Comment: But i dont knw what is the value of $r[1] which you have used

Comment: Already gladoscc says $r[1] is 0.11 so there is no need to put static in place of $r[1]....so sujit singh no need to edit my ans right..??